# How to convert RDD to DataFrame in Spark Streaming, not just Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, rdd

How can I convert `RDD` to `DataFrame` in `Spark Streaming`, not just `Spark`?

I saw this example, but it requires `SparkContext`.

```
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc) 
import sqlContext.implicits._
rdd.toDF()
```

In my case I have `StreamingContext`. Should I then create `SparkContext` inside `foreach`? It looks too crazy... So, how to deal with this issue? My final goal (if it might be useful) is to save the `DataFrame` in Amazon S3 using `rdd.toDF.write.format("json").saveAsTextFile("s3://iiiii/ttttt.json");`, which is not possible for `RDD` without converting it to `DataFrame` (as I know).

```
myDstream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("My App")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc) 
    import sqlContext.implicits._
    rdd.toDF()
}
```

Comment: check this link https://docs.cloud.databricks.com/docs/latest/databricks_guide/07%20Spark%20Streaming/08%20Write%20Output%20To%20S3.html

Comment: @Shankar: where does he define AWS access key?

Comment: whatever written inside `foreachRDD` is executed at the Driver, so you can create `sqlContext` and convert the `rdd` to `DF` and then write to `S3`.

Comment: @Shankar: I still misunderstand: should I create both StreamingContext and SparkContext outside of `foreachRDD`? In the example that you posted I cannot find where `sqlContext` is defined. I try to reproduce this example and it gives me an error that `sqlContext` cannot be found. I do not want to overcomplicate things, that's why I ask about the simplest possible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `sqlContext` outside `foreachRDD` ,Once you convert the `rdd` to DF using `sqlContext`, you can write into S3.

**For example:**

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("My App")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc) 
import sqlContext.implicits._
myDstream.foreachRDD { rdd =>

    val df = rdd.toDF()
    df.write.format("json").saveAsTextFile("s3://iiiii/ttttt.json")
}
```

**Update:**

Even you can create `sqlContext` inside `foreachRDD` which is going to execute on Driver.

Comment: I tested this example. It says `Cannot resolve symbol` refering to `saveAsTextFile`. I use scala 2.11 and spark 1.6.2.

Comment: try `text` http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter

Comment: Another issue is that I get an error about multiple SparkContext's. I assume that's because I have  both SparkContext and StreamingContext:  `val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(refreshingIntervalSeconds.toInt))
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
    sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", Utils.getAWS_ACCESS_KEY())
    sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", Utils.getAWS_SECRET_KEY())
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)`

Comment: try `val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(refreshingIntervalSeconds.toInt))`

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following answer which contains a scala magic cell inside a python notebook:
[How to convert Spark Streaming data into Spark DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35245648/how-to-convert-spark-streaming-data-into-spark-dataframe/50894876#50894876)