# SparkStreaming: DirectStream RDD to dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am working on spark streaming context which is getting data from kafka topic in avro serialization as below.

```
val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
  "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092",
  "schema.registry.url" -> "http://localhost:8081",
  "key.deserializer" -> "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer",
  "value.deserializer" -> "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer",
  "group.id" -> "1"
)
```

Using Kafka utils i am creating Direct stream as below

```
val topics = Set("mysql-foobar")


val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
  ssc,
  PreferConsistent,
  Subscribe[String,String](
    topics,
    kafkaParams)
)
```

I am also writing the data to console as

```
stream.foreachRDD ( rdd => {
  rdd.foreachPartition(iterator => {
    while (iterator.hasNext) {
      val next = iterator.next()
      println(next.value())
    }
  })
})
```

Now i want to create data frame from these RDD's. Is it possible i had reviewed and tested many solution from stackoverflow but getting some issues with them. Stackoverflow Solution are [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46200552/use-schema-to-convert-consumerrecord-value-to-dataframe-in-spark-kafka) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39996549/how-to-convert-rdd-to-dataframe-in-spark-streaming-not-just-spark) also.
My output looks as below

```
{"c1": 4, "c2": "Jarry", "create_ts": 1536758512000, "update_ts": 1537204805000}
```

Comment: Look at the Structured Streaming documentation. Don't use Dstream. https://github.com/AbsaOSS/ABRiS

Comment: what are the sbt library dependencies to import this za.co.absa.abris.avro.schemas.policy.SchemaRetentionPolicies?

Comment: Should be mentioned on the github page https://github.com/AbsaOSS/ABRiS/blob/master/README.md#maven-dependency

Comment: i had tried this with structured streaming and following the suggested steps but i am getting error can you please review them that where i am doing wrong.

Comment: val schemaRegistryConfs = Map(
      SchemaManager.PARAM_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL   -> "http://localhost:8081",
      SchemaManager.PARAM_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_TOPIC -> "mysql-foobar",
      SchemaManager.PARAM_VALUE_SCHEMA_ID       -> "latest" 
    )
val df = spark.
      readStream.
      format("kafka").
      option("subscribe", "mysql-foobar").
      option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092").
      fromAvro("value",schemaRegistryConfs)(RETAIN_SELECTED_COLUMN_ONLY)

Comment: I've not used that library, but the schema registry url needs an HTTP prefix on it

Comment: ok now the code is running without error but getting nulls in values.

Comment: I think you copied the wrong section https://github.com/AbsaOSS/ABRiS/blob/master/README.md#reading-avro-binary-records-from-confluent-platform-using-schema-registry-as-spark-structured-streams-and-performing-regular-sql-queries-on-them

Comment: Thanks I had searched for it but could not find that i think you should answer the question i will mark that as correct.

Comment: but i think  its much easier to implement with just 2 lines of code by including the required library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Confluent serializers, and they don't provide easy integrations with Spark at this time, you can checkout a relatively new library on Github by AbsaOSS that helps with this.

But basically, you use Spark Structured Streaming to get DataFrames, don't try to use Dstream to RDD to Dataframe...

You can find [examples of what you're looking for here](https://github.com/AbsaOSS/ABRiS/blob/master/README.md#reading-avro-binary-records-from-confluent-platform-using-schema-registry-as-spark-structured-streams-and-performing-regular-sql-queries-on-them)

Also see other examples at [Integrating Spark Structured Streaming with the Kafka Schema Registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48882723/integrating-spark-structured-streaming-with-the-kafka-schema-registry)